# C# UDP Отправка сервера к клиенту байт выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, сеть, udp

Всем привет! Когда сервер отправляет байт данных на уже отключенный клиент то я получаю вот такое исключение:

[image: Exception]

Kак узнать клиент доступен ли?
Как утсранить эту проблему или обоити
?

Искал в интернете, нашел пару похожих вопросов но у них другие проблемы в конце решил спросить тут.

Server:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 23000);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        EndPoint EP = (EndPoint)sender;

        int i;
        sock.Bind(ipep);

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                i = sock.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref EP); // ошибка появляется здесь
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            }

            // нажимаем на любую клаву чтобы получить ошибку
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу чтобы отправить байт клиенту и получить ошибку");
            Console.ReadKey();
            sock.SendTo(buffer, i, SocketFlags.None, EP);
```

Client:

```
        int serverPort = 23000;
        string hostName = "127.0.0.1";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        EndPoint remote;
        IPEndPoint endPoint;
        Socket server;

        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(hostName), serverPort);
        server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        remote = (EndPoint)sender;

        buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("me send");
        server.SendTo(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, endPoint);

        // выходим из клиента чтобы сервер отправил отключенному клиенту;
```

Comment: Не совсем ответ, но может вам приготится... Попробуйте реализовать сервер и клиент через UdpClient

Comment: И попробуйте подключаться не на 127.0.0.1, а на конкретный интерфейс. А еще лучше запустите клиента и сервера на разных тачках.

Comment: Как мне сделать тогда через UdpClient? Я отправляю на сервер данные но от сервера ничего не получаю (это через UdpClient делал), я пробовал через VPS сервер но все равно получаю исключение в коде.

Comment: [Вот](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level4/4_7.php) пример как сделать через UdpClient. Но скорее всего там тоже будет исключение, на 127.0.0.1

Comment: В этом пример та же история клиент серверу может отправить но сервер клиенту никак. Все примеры одинаковые в моем примере мне надо просто как то исправить ошибку. И все будет работать. Неделя прошла со дня поиска ответа на этот вопрос :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.ReceiveFrom внутри использует функцию [recvfrom](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom). Она соотвественно 
может завершится с ошибкой **WSAECONNRESET**(код у неё 10054). В документации на функцию **recvfrom** указанано следующие описание ошибки **WSAECONNRESET**:

> The virtual circuit was reset by the remote side executing a hard or
>   abortive close. The application should close the socket; it is no
>   longer usable. On a UDP-datagram socket this error indicates a
>   previous send operation resulted in an ICMP Port Unreachable message.

В кратце на русском: Если хост разорвет соединение и после этого будет вызыван **send**, то последующая операция чтения завершится с этой ошибкой.

Соответственно чтобы решить вашу проблему, нужно использовать примерно такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 23000));

        while (true) {
            var i = 0;

            EndPoint clientPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            try {
                i = socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref clientPoint);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == 10054) {
                // ни чего не делаем идем дальше
                continue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                break;
            }

            socket.SendTo(buffer, i, SocketFlags.None, clientPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:**
Есть еще магическая константа **SIO_UDP_CONNRESET**, которая вроде убирает генерирование этой ошибки. Но я не уверен, что она влияет только на этот случай поэтому код приводить с ней не буду.

Comment: Кстати, я исправил пример UdpClient котороую вы мне отправили, сервер теперь может отправлять клиенту, переделал всё на UdpClient. А эту проблему с исклюением я сегодня посмотрю смотря на ваш ответ. Спосибо вы очень помогли :)